# How can I bring up a non-boot (ONBOOT=no) network interface with iproute2?

Tags: centos, networking, rhel, iproute

Have a network interface that does not come up on boot-up:

```
[belminf@tito ~]$ grep ONBOOT /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3
ONBOOT=no
```

I know I could do the following for DHCP:

```
 [belminf@tito ~]$ ip link set enp0s3 up
 [belminf@tito ~]$ dhclient enp0s3
```

Or, for static IP:

```
 [belminf@tito ~]$ ip link set enp0s3 up
 [belminf@tito ~]$ ip addr add 192.0.2.11/24 dev enp0s3
```

However, is there a way to load the configuration from `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` like `ifup ensp0s3` would have done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In RHEL 7+, you'll have to use `nmcli` command for permanent change. `nmcli` command uses `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-con_name` file first, also when you modify connection properties with `nmcli` it will write to `ifcfg-con_name` file. So, to automatically start connection, you need to use following:

```
nmcli con mod enp0s3 connection.autoconnect yes
```

It will change `ONBOOT` property to `yes`.

In order, to load newly changed configuration file, you need to use (otherwise it will load during next boot):

```
nmcli con down enp0s3
nmcli con up enp0s3
```

**Good luck!**

Answer (score 2):

`ifup enp0s3` should bring up the interface and configure it.

You might want to review the [Network Interfaces](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Network_Interfaces.html) chapter of the RHEL manual. [§10.3. “Interface Control Scripts”](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-control.html) mentions using `ifup`.

`ifconfig enp0s3 up` should not load any configuration from `ifcfg-enp0s3`, by the way. See e.g., [What is the difference between 'ifconfig up eth0' and 'ifup eth0'?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/27166) on the RedHat Knowledge Base.